# podman change directory ownership after mounting as volume - how to change it back?

Tags: volume, podman

I'm running podman in rootless mode. After mounting a directory (-v) it changed its ownership to subgid and now I can't access it. How can I change the ownership back without root privileges?

podman unshare chown   doesn't work: getting
chown: changing ownership of '***': Invalid argument

Comment: Are you after "keep-id"? https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/options/userns.container.html

Comment: Not really, it's too late for that :) podman changed my mounted directory ownership and now I can't access it.

Comment: The "root" user should be able to chown it from outside. Obviously that will stop it working inside the container, at which point you'll want the keep-id stuff

Comment: You might want open a shell `podman unshare` to be able to chmod. If you do `podman unshare chmod 0:0 file` the file will afterwards have the ownership of your regular user on the host. (This solution does not require sudo permissions on the host)

Comment: That worked great, Erik, thank you very much! Wish I understood what happened though.